# Update ECS service with AWS CLI avoiding CFN drift

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Currently I deployed the first version of an ECS service via CFN using resolve:ssm to add a dynamic reference to the container image tag and to the task definition ARN. Then I update the service using AWS cli in a Gitlab-ci pipeline, in this way I can avoid most of the drift issues but not all. Which is the best way to avoid drift completely? Could I update the parameter on SSM (the image tag in this case) and to invoke an “aws sam deploy” in a Gitlab’s job?

I’m using the dynamic reference because I’d like to avoid updating the CFN template in the gitlab’s job and then commit it

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of static values in your CFN templates and a workflow to prevent issues when cloudformation updates that cause a service update are applied.

In the cloud-formation templates, the image tag is defined just as a static name, like the environment name, e.g. `dev`/`staging`/`production`. This never changes.

Through the CICD workflow, new images are built and tagged with a unique tag. That unique tag is used to update the service. Then immediately after the update succeeds, we add the same static tag used from the CFN templates (e.g. `dev`/`staging`/`production`) is added to the new image in ECR.

So, in steps:

1. Build image tag with unique tag, push to ECR
2. Create a new task definition with the new image tag and update the service
3. Wait for successful service stabilization
4. Push the static tag (the one used in the CFN template) to the same new image that just successfully deployed

This has the following important effects:

- Because the templates use a static tag value, CFN will never think it needs to update the service because of a tag change. You don't ever have tag changes in your CFN changesets.
- By ensuring the tag used in CFN in ECR follows the current image applied on the service, whenever a subsequent CFN update occurs that causes a service update for any other reason, it will use the same image that is already in use.

This is similar to the SSM parameter approach, if you update the parameter as part of your deployment workflow.

There is technically still [drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html) (that is: the resource changed outside of what is in the current known CFN state), however the issues that can be caused by that drift are mitigated through the workflow.

One other option that avoids drift entirely is to always use CFN to update the service and never update the service outside of CFN.